# Property collection does not exist on type AngularFirestoreModule

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular10

Cordial saludo estimados.

Solo llevo unas cuantas horas aprendiendo Angular, estoy siguiendo un video-tutorial de iniciación. Presento un error: Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreModule' cuando inicializo la variable que contendrá la colección desde firebase

Dejo los codigos para su revisión, quedo atento a sus comentarios

Codigo del compoente con el error:

```
   import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-empleados',
  templateUrl: './list-empleados.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-empleados.component.css']
})
export class ListEmpleadosComponent implements OnInit {
  // posible fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322583/cannot-find-angular-fire-firestore-module-error-in-vscode
  // variable de tipo obervable: configuración de firebase, se debe inicializar en el constructor
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor( db: AngularFirestoreModule ) {
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Aqui la configuración del app modul ts:

```
    import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// modulos
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

// componentes
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListEmpleadosComponent } from './components/list-empleados/list-empleados.component';
import { CreateEmpleadoComponent } from './components/create-empleado/create-empleado.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListEmpleadosComponent,
    CreateEmpleadoComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

La configuración del entorno:

```
 // This file can be replaced during build by using the `fileReplacements` array.
// `ng build --prod` replaces `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts`.
// The list of file replacements can be found in `angular.json`.

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "fsdfdfds-fsdfsd-fdsfdsfdsf",
    authDomain: "dfsd-fdfdsfds.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "ffrgre-gregergr",
    storageBucket: "gdfgdfgd-gggfd.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "dfsf4",
    appId: "1:gdrdrd4444:web:6c099d16cb56de4534abb9"
  }
};

/*
 * For easier debugging in development mode, you can import the following file
 * to ignore zone related error stack frames such as `zone.run`, `zoneDelegate.invokeTask`.
 *
 * This import should be commented out in production mode because it will have a negative impact
 * on performance if an error is thrown.
 */
// import 'zone.js/dist/zone-error';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Y package.json

```
 {
  "name": "empleados",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3",
    "firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1200",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "open": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

Agradecería mucho de su asesoría o solución, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo de forma urgente que no publiques las API keys de tu proyecto de firebase, ya que es información sensible. Cámbialas por datos de prueba como "asdasdasd"

Comment: Y si es posible vuelve a generar las credenciales del proyecto, asi te aseguras que nadie que haya entrado aquí utilice las credenciales publicadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar `AngularFirestoreModule` en el constructor:

```js
  constructor( db: AngularFirestoreModule ) {
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
   }
```

Debes utilizar `AngularFirestore`:

```js
  constructor( db: AngularFirestore ) {
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
   }
```

Ya que `AngularFirestoreModule` solo lo debes usar en el import del modulo padre donde declares tu componente.

Puedes consultar más [aquí](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md)

Comment: Cordial saludo Andres, muchas gracias por tu efectiva solución

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado